# How secure is the encryption with OTP and an OneRNG?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, file-encryption

I bought an HWRND last week. What do you think, how secure is the encryption with that and the OTP? See the OneRNG theory of operation [here](http://www.moonbaseotago.com/onerng/theory.html).

Comment: Added with OTP? How are you going to transfer that?

Comment: I want to read a random stream from the device and encrypt a file with this and the OTP. Every byte from file will XOR with every byte from the stream.

Comment: Then how are going to store the OTP key? Do you really know how the One Time Pad is working?

Comment: In my opinion a byte will XOR with a other byte. I can store the random bytes in a separate file. If I want to decrypt the file, Do the same with my random file and the cipher file.

Comment: (first plaintextbyte xor first randombyte, second plaintextbyte xor second randombyte... and so on)

Comment: I think the issue kelalaka is taking here is the fact that while you _can_ use that RNG for OTP (-like) encryption this doesn't solve the issue that now you have an encrypted file and a key as large as that file and you now have the same problem as originally: You have sensitive data that you want to protect, but this time it's the OTP key instead of the plaintext.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure how to solve this Problem. I could move the key to a external device but that isn't a good solution. And the is to long for a passwordmanager :(

Comment: A good password manager like keypass, AES256-GCM-SIV

Comment: But then you're protecting the OTP key with something less powerful than an OTP (like AES256-GCM-SIV), and you could just use that to encrypt the plaintext for the same security, and have a much easier job of key management. Really that's the core paradox of OTPs: they're perfectly secure, and almost perfectly useless. Only in the rare situation where you can pre-share a massive amount of key material (more than you'll ever use) with the endpoints, safely, are they useful.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus This is not a "rare" use case. It's the de facto usage for OTPs. Hiding 8K UHD films is not. History has proven that over and over and over. You pre-share the keys before mounting an operation. War can be declared in a text message, and 1 MB ~ 6,000 messages.

Comment: I'm saying that the case where OTPs are usable is rare out of all the cases where encryption is useful. Not that the opportunity to pre-share key material is rare when using OTPs, that would be dumb, since it's required to use OTPs.